# COMBOBOX is not vertically sizable wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

i am wondering if there is a way to size a combobox vertically

This does not work

```
    self.combo1 = wx.ComboBox(self, -1, value='dsadas', pos=wx.Point(10, 30),
        size=wx.Size(120, 423450), choices=areaList)
```

It will size for x but it will not size for the y value. If we change the y value, the combo box will remain the same.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the wx.ComboBox will allow the vertical size to be set if the native widget doesn't accept that argument. Remember, wxPython wraps the native widgets of the platform and must conform to those widget's limitations.

On the other hand, you CAN use the ComboCtrl (wx.combo.ComboCtrl) and change both its vertical and horizontal sizes because it is is a custom control. I tested this using the wxPython demo on my Windows 7 64-bit box.

Comment: it seems to be working well, ive looking on the API but is there a way to assign a list to the ComboCtrl such as the 'choices' option in Comboboxes?

Comment: theres also no option to "SetItems"

Comment: The ComboCtrl appears to work in a fundamentally different way than the ComboBox in that it draws the pop-up part itself using DCs or similar. So no, the methods are not the same. You might want to go on the official wxPython mailing list and ask for tips, but I suspect you'll just have to subclass it or create a custom control yourself if you want those features.